# Получение данных от увлажнителя воздуха Polaris

Tags: android, request

Приобрел увлажнитель воздуха Polaris puh 2300. В нем есть гидростат и он умеет передавать данные на мобильное приложение polaris. Как можно узнать url и данные аутентификации для запроса данных вне приложения ?

Comment: довольно высока вероятность что юзается апи какое-то внутреннее, попробуйте поискать в сети на сайте разработчиков увлажнителя, может апи будет доступно публично, плюс может доки будут по тому что вас интересует.

Comment: Спрашивайте производителя, не факт что он готов открывать свое АПИ третьим лицам.

Comment: попробуйте поснифить трафик между приложением и устройством.